# Applying WebView on setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

Currently I'm a beginner in android. Right now I'm trying to make my ListView item open a layout which contain WebView when any item is clicked. Each item will direct to a different page. But I'm not sure how can I achieve this. This is my code.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, null);
    }

    FeedItem p = getItem(position);

    if (p != null) {
        TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_text);

        if (tt1 != null) {
            tt1.setText(p.getTitle());
        }


        if (tt2 != null) {
            tt2.setText(p.getPubDate());
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                FeedItem q = getItem(position);
                if(q.getLink() != null){
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + q.getLink(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }




    return v;

}
```

Comment: Try to make a great way of asking question make clear all needs and issues then post your question because of it make effect your reputation okey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question is totally opinion based. both can be used as per app's requirement.

### Default Browser

it is easy to use just 4 or file lines and you are good to go. but it gets user out of application.

**How to use it.**

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(YOUR_URL));
startActivity(intent);
```

### WebView

can be used as a part of application. you need to create on activity containing webview and call intent from where you want to open webview.

**Example**

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"  
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <WebView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/webView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

java

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity  {

   private WebView wv1;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);


      wv1.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
      wv1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      wv1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
      wv1.loadUrl(your_url);

   }
}
```

and just call this from where you want to open `Webview`.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,WebViewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

refer this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm).

I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify little bit according to your requirement and need to put your import your package.

```
if(q.getLink() != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BrowserActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("url", q.getLink());
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

**BrowserActivity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.yourproject.R;


public class BrowserActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    WebView webview;

    public BrowserActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.comment_detail);

        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        Log.d("URL ", url);

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

        webview.loadUrl(url);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {

            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // do your stuff here
                MyApplication.hideTransparentProgressDialog();
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(CommentDetails.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**comment_detail.xml**

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/headerTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    layout="@layout/title_bar_layout_job_info" />

<WebView
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerTV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview">

</WebView>
```

Answer (score 1):

To open browser use intent:

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

and for [webview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) :

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

JAVA Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

you can also load your own html file on WebView.